# Loading a Type Library via PowerShell and scripting Windows Live Writer

Tags: windows, com, powershell, windows-live-writer

I'm very new to COM and Windows programming/scripting in general. What I was trying to do is scripting Windows Live Writer; according to the documentation before I can call

```
  $o = New-Object -c WindowsLiveWriter.Application
```

I need to load the TLB first, so I should call the `add-type` command, unfortunately it fails:

```
PS C:\Users\NoWhereMan> add-type windowslivewriter.application
Add-Type : c:\Users\NoWhereMan\AppData\Local\Temp\a7ifbimo.0.cs(1) : A namespace does not directly contain members such
 as fields or methods
c:\Users\NoWhereMan\AppData\Local\Temp\a7ifbimo.0.cs(1) : >>> windowslivewriter.application
At line:1 char:9
+ add-type <<<<  windowslivewriter.application
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\NoWher...elds or methods:CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. There were compilation errors.
At line:1 char:9
+ add-type <<<<  windowslivewriter.application
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

for what it's worth, **I'm running Windows7 x64**

**EDIT**: x64 was the key issue, I needed to run PSH as a x86 process

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to use add-type for a COM object it should infer members from the objects IDispatch interface. AFAIK add-type is only for adding a new .NET assembly.

Comment: as I commented to Richard, I was mislead by the error I got from new-object which was in fact thrown because I was using a 64 bit PSH process. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help add-type`:

> Adds a Microsoft .NET Framework type (a class) to a Windows PowerShell session.

but `windowslivewriter.application` is not a .NET type.

PowerShell (PSH) directly supports COM objects, you do not need to take any special steps to load the Type Library (TLB)<sup>1</sup>, just call the methods diretcly as given in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738851.aspx) for the component. E.g.:

```
$lw = New-Object -com WindowsLiveWriter.Application   
$lw.NetPost()
```

to launch the new post editor.

Summary: you do *not* need to load the TLB first.

Under 64bit Windows, you might need to ensure you are running a 32bit instance ("x86") of PSH to do this (depending if the Live Writer component runs in or out of process).

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, this only applies to COM types that support scripting with IDispatch, but in practice there are few that don't.

Comment: I was mislead by the error message I got with New-Object -c ; but in fact it was thrown because I was running a x64 instance of PSH instead of x86, thank you!