# ActiveDs COM not visible in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com, active-directory

I hear that COM type libraries are supposed to be automatically accessible in PowerShell with no explicit load. So why doesn't ActiveDs work?

```
PS > new-object -com ActiveDs.LargeInteger
New-Object : Cannot load COM type ActiveDs.LargeInteger.
At line:1 char:11
+ new-object <<<<  -com ActiveDs.LargeInteger
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotLoadComObjectType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

This is a follow-up to [Use PowerShell to wrap an existing COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248032/use-powershell-to-wrap-an-existing-com-object#comment30320638_20248032) which asks a related but different question.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you explore using the DirectoryEntry as there is virtually nothing that can be accomplished via ActiveDS that cannot be accomplished using DirectoryEntry.

Object creation

```
#$dn = [adsi] "LDAP://192.168.30.200:389/dc=dom,dc=fr"
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.234.200:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","administrateur@dom.fr","admin")

# OU creation
$Monou = $dn.create("OrganizationalUnit", "ou=Monou")
$Monou.put("Description", "Une description")
$Res = $Monou.Setinfo()

# User creation
$objUtilisateur = $Monou.create("inetOrgPerson", "cn=Marc Assin")
$objUtilisateur.setinfo()
```

Object search

```
#$dn = [adsi] "LDAP://192.168.30.200:389/dc=dom,dc=fr"
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.234.200:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","administrateur@dom.fr","admin")

# Recherche d'un utilisateur
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$Rech.filter = "((userPrincipalName=phocquet@dom.fr))"
$Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");  
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon");  
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("otherHomePhone"); # téléphone domicile autre

$liste = $Rech.FindOne()
#$liste = $Rech.findall()
```

---

Edited :

The datas ('lockoutDuration', 'forceLogoff', 'lockOutObservationWindow', 'maxPwdAge', 'minPwdAge) you are looking for are in fact attributes of the domain object itself.

```
# Here is the way to retreive the domain object
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://DomainDnsNameOrIP:389/DC=SILOGIX,DC=fr","toto@SILOGIX.FR","totoPwd")
```

Now if you look at the result of `$dn | fl *` most of the attributes can be retreived writting `$dn.Properties.PROPERTYNAMEHERE[0]` -> `$dn.Properties.minPwdLength[0]`. But some of then will give you the result : `System.__ComObject`. For these last ones the method I use the following :

```
$dsLookFor = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$dsLookFor.SearchScope = "base"; 
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("modifiedcount");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lockOutObservationWindow");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("maxPwdAge");
$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("minPwdAge");
$res = $dsLookFor.FindOne()
$res.Properties.lockoutobservationwindow[0]
# An attribute may be multivalued so $res.Properties.lockoutobservationwindow should be a collection
$a = $res.Properties.lockoutobservationwindow[0]
# Retrive the duration (you'll use datetime structure for dates)
[timespan]([math]::Abs($a))
```

Comment: Actually `DirectoryServices` is the whole reason that I need `ActiveDs`. DS returns some COM objects from ADS.

Comment: Ok, but which type do you need ? you can see in the samples above that I reach DirectoryServices types.

Comment: Many properties return COM objects, including 'lockoutDuration', 'forceLogoff', 'lockOutObservationWindow', 'maxPwdAge', 'minPwdAge'

Comment: Why would `Abs` succeed on a `__ComObject`? It doesn't for me:

    `$fl = ($adroot.Properties.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.PropertyName -eq 'forceLogoff' })[0]
[math]::Abs($fl)
Cannot find an overload for "Abs" and the argument count: "1".
    At line:1 char:1
    + [math]::Abs($fl)
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest`

Comment: In my examples I just add `$n = $dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("forceLogoff");` and after `findOne` I can see `$res.Properties.forcelogoff[0]` it gives `-9223372036854775808` (-1 -> never). BE CAREFULL `$res.Properties.forceLogoff[0]` gives nothing here `forcelogoff` seems to be case sensitive you have to type it in lowercases.