# Use PowerShell to create instance of COM object

Tags: c#, powershell, com, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to use SAP/BusinessObjects' Universe Design Tool (UDT) in a PowerShell session.

I registered the type library:

```
C:\> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\designer.tlb
```

I attempted to create an instance of the Designer in PowerShell directly:

```
PS> $app = New-Object -ComObject Designer.Application
System.__ComObject
```

The instance doesn't have any of the expected properties and methods:

```
PS> $app | get-member

   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetType                   Method     type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

Next, I created a C# `Cmdlet` that wraps some of the Designer's functionality:

```
[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon.Open, "Universe")]
    [OutputType(typeof(Designer.Universe))]
    public class OpenUniverse  : System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet
    {

    Designer.Application application = null;

    [System.Management.Automation.Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    [Alias("FullName")]
    public string[] Paths
    {
        get { return paths; }
        set { paths = value; }
    }
    private string[] paths;

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        application = new Application();
        application.Interactive = false;

        try
        {
          application.Logon("user", "password", "cluster", "secWinAd"); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    } # /BeginProcessing

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        Designer.Universe universe = null;

        try
        {
            foreach (string path in Paths)
            {
                universe = application.Universes.Open(path);
                WriteObject(universe);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
        {
          # ...
        }
        finally
        {
           if ( universe != null ) { universe.Close(); }
        }

    } # /ProcessRecord

} # / OpenUniverse
```

When run within a Visual Studio 2010 test, the code returns the expected object.

I created a manifest that references the assembly that was created by the project, then imported the module into a new PowerShell session.

```
PS> $unv = Open-Universe 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\Universes\Foo.unv'
PS> $unv
System.__ComObject
```

Is there a way to get PowerShell's reflection to generate the `System.__ComObject` instance's properties and methods?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248032/use-powershell-to-wrap-an-existing-com-object)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in order `PowerShell` can display instance's properties and methods (late binding), the COM instance has to implement the `ITypeInfo` interface.